# Swift3 - Spritekit Sprite not full size

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to have a game over screen pop up, using SKSpriteNodes and it scales correctly on first try but from the second, the whole game over is small.

```
func spawnPlayAgainBTN() {
    playAgain = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonPlay")
    playAgain.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX + 54, y: self.frame.midY - 10)
    playAgain.zPosition = 8
    playAgain.setScale(0)
    self.addChild(playAgain)
    playAgain.run(SKAction.scale(to: 0.4, duration: 0.4))

}

func spawnMainMenuBTN() {
    mainMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "buttonMainMenu ")
    mainMenu.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 54, y: self.frame.midY - 10)
    mainMenu.zPosition = 8
    mainMenu.setScale(0)
    self.addChild(mainMenu)
    mainMenu.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.4))
}


func spawnGameOverScreen() {
    gameOverBG = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gameOverBG")
    gameOverBG.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    gameOverBG.zPosition = 7
    gameOverBG.setScale(0)
    self.addChild(gameOverBG)
    gameOverBG.run(SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.4))
    spawnPlayAgainBTN()
    spawnMainMenuBTN()
    isRunningGame = false
    isShowingGameOver = true
}
```

Comment: Check the scale for the relevant node when appropriate and see why it is small.

Comment: You have report too few informations , what about your node removals? Correct your `setScale(0)` with `setScale(0.01)` and see what happened..